# Get value "8" from a wordpress url: mywebsite.com/profile/8/

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I get that value "8" from a wordpress url: mywebsite.com/profile/8/

```
    $current_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url_params = explode( '/', $current_uri );
    $the_value = $url_params[2];
```

But seems a little dirty to me. Any thoughts? Thank you

NOTE: that "8" changes. Not always "8".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In word press you can get query variable by below function:

```
get_query_var( $var, $default );
```

$var is The variable key to retrieve. (e.g. profile, paged, id,  etc. )

$default Value to return if the query variable is not set.

check below link: [Query var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

Comment: But i dont know the variable name: $var. Is there a function to list all the possible variable names? Im on that page: mywebsite.com/profile/8/ and i need to get the value "8" programatically.

Comment: @karlosuccess: put global $wp_query; in header or starting of functionality of particular page. you can check all query string for particular URL by var_dump($wp_query) or echo '<pre>'; print_r($wp_query); echo '</pre>'; . Where you might see array in which key which is containing value of 8. from there you can get query string for it.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expression like this.

```
<?php
//$current_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// For Demo I have declared it as string below.
$current_uri="mywebsite.com/profile/8/";
preg_match('/(\d+)\/$/', $current_uri, $m );
print $m[1];
?>
```

**Regex:** `(\d+)\/$`

Above regex will **extract a number(\d+) appearing before last( $ quantifier ) /(slash)**

Capturing it into a **group** by using `()` around `\d+` extracted number is retrieved in array `$m[1]`.

**<kbd>[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/i50BIS)</kbd>**